# How I can add style into my tooltip function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have this code.

```
tooltip: function() {
    $(".form-item-label.info")
    .append("<p title='' class='icon-info-sign info'></p>")
    .tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "tool",
        show: null,
        position: {
            my: "right bottom",
            at: "right top",
            using: function(position, feedback) {
                $(this).css({top: position.top+80, left: position.left-30});
                $("<div>")
                    .addClass("tooltip-arrow")
                    .appendTo(this);
            }
        },
        content: function() {
            var msg = "<p>Some text</p>";
            return msg;
        }
    });
});
```

How I can add style in my tooltip function? not from styles, but from key value like tooltipClass:"tool", show: null, position... content... STYLE: ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it with default tooltip code.

You have to modify the library, you could fork tooltip.js and apply style/class attribute to tooltip element.